# pdfLaTeX in AUCTeX doesn't make pdf files with some fonts

Tags: pdftex, auctex

I like AUCTeX for edit TeX files. I can generate pdf files with some fonts (like New Century Schoolbook, Helvetica or Charter), but not with other (XCharter and urw-Garamond, for example). The installation works well, I can generate pdf files from command line and with TeXstudio with this command:

> pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "filename".tex

But with AUCTeX (with the fonts mentioned before) I get any pdf file and

> filename.synctex.gz(busy)

and in logfile:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file XCharter-Roman-tlf-ts1--base): Font
>   XCharter-Roma n-tlf-ts1--base at 720 not found
>   ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

but the XCharter font ist installed.

I use MiKTeX 2.9 in Windows 8.1. I use GNU Emacs 24.5.1 with AUCTeX 11.89.

This input:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000
\setlength{\parindent}{0.6cm} % Default is 15pt.

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\sffamily
\begin{center}{\Large \textbf{Los sentidos}}\end{center}

\rmfamily
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

works fine, but this:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000
\setlength{\parindent}{0.6cm} % Default is 15pt.

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \sffamily
    \begin{center}{\Large \textbf{Los sentidos}}\end{center}

    \rmfamily
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

fails (there are only changes in the fourth line) in Emacs/AUCTeX.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This does not seen to be related to auctex but rather a latex problem. How exactly are you accessing those fonts? Please provide a minimal example

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same texsystem in both cases? Compare the log-file of the auctex compilation with the log-file of the compilation on the command line.

Comment: What is your distribution?